# Using DOCUMENT_ROOT for dynamic path

Tags: php

I am making a website and I want a dynamic path stored in a variable named `$_SESSION['path']`, so that later in this project I can access files easier when working in a deep directory.
In head.php I start the session and set the `$_SESSION['path']` variable equal to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.
When I try to go to the style.css file in head.php it doesn't work.
The css file is just for refference, I do not only need the path for the css file, but also for images and other links.

My directory looks like this:

```
> portfolio
  > css
    style.css
  > main
    footer.php (for the footer)
    head.php (for the head)
    header.php (for the header)
  index.php
```

head.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    ?>


     I cut the bootstrap and other links out so it reads more easy.


    <!-- CSS Files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $_SESSION['path'] . '/portfolio/css/style.css' ?>">
</head>
<body>
```

index.php:

```
<?php 
    include dirname(__FILE__) . '/main/head.php'; 
    include dirname(__FILE__) . '/main/header.php';
?>
    <h1>This should turn blue when style.css works</h1>
<?php
    include dirname(__FILE__) . '/main/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Man, it makes absolutely no sense. Why would you want to use $_SESSION['path'] instead of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']? It's just nonsense.

Comment: To answer your queston, you CANNOT use document root for css. See https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is a file system path on server's disk, but CSS files are accessed through URLs as network resources. Your CSS root path is almost always going to be hard-coded and static. In your case it seems to be `/css`.